# Latex Table of Content problem with Space

Tags: table-of-contents

The problem is **space of table of content** as it can be seen form the diagram. How to specify the same space for each section and subsection and update table of content accordingly. [image]

Thank you very much for suggestion.

Comment: Is "19" the number of the section or chapter?

Comment: 19.10 is automatically generated, part of table of content. Section name is- Definition- Code Book.

Comment: could you provide a complete MWE that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I take it, then, that "19" is the number of the *chapter*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft) package may be your friend. Specifically, use its macro

```
\cftsetindents{<header type>}{<start>}{<width>}
```

to set the starting positions (measured from the left-hand edge of the text block) and widths of the "blocks" that contain the numbers corresponding to header types such as `chap`, `section`, `subsection`, etc.

The following might be a solution that works for you.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{1.5em}
\cftsetindents{section}{1.5em}{3em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{chapter}{18}   % just for this example
\chapter{A chapter with many sections}
\setcounter{section}{9} % just for this example
\section{Definition-Code Book}
\section{Feistel cipher\slash Network}
\section{Key exchange}
\section{Discrete algorithm}
\end{document}
```